# How to Remotely Debug code as sudo with CLion?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gdb, sudo, remote-debugging, clion

I am using CLion in my Windows PC to run and debug code on a Raspberry Pi, using the Remote development option with GDB.

How can I make that remote code on my Raspberry Pi run as root when I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `Full Remote Mode` i.e. you created new toolchain with `Remote Host` option as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html).

There is no way to run GDB with `sudo`. But you can make CLion ssh into your raspberry with root account. Just change settings in `Credentials` section. (Also make sure you have SSH root login enabled.)

If you ever need more control over GDB, go with gdbserver.

Comment: Hmm interesting, ok, lots of stuff for me to read then, thanks

Answer (score 0):

there  is a way, but not recommended, you can log as root in clion.

1. Enable root login via SSH

   - edit ssh_config file: `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
   - add this line `PermitRootLogin yes`
   - save the file
   - restart the ssh server `systemctl restart sshd`
2. Set a root password if there isn't one already: `sudo passwd root`
3. In Clion configure the `Remote Host` to login as root (Files->setting->Build, Execution, Deployment->Toolchains->Credentials). Procedure described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/remote-projects-support.html).

This worked for me.